# What's the difference between FastAPI background tasks and Celery tasks?

Tags: python, celery, scheduled-tasks, fastapi, background-task

Recently I read something about this and the point was that celery is more productive.

Now, I can't find detailed information about the difference between these two and what should be the best way to use them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Straight from the [documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/background-tasks/#caveat):

> If you need to perform **heavy** background computation and you don't
> necessarily need it to be run by the same process (for example, you
> don't need to share memory, variables, etc), you might benefit from
> using other bigger tools like [Celery](https://docs.celeryq.dev/).
>
> They tend to require more complex configurations, a message/job queue
> manager, like RabbitMQ or Redis, but they **allow you to run
> background tasks in multiple processes**, and especially, in multiple
> servers.
>
> To see an example, check the [Project Generators](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/project-generation/), they all include
> Celery already configured.
>
> But if you need to access variables and objects from the **same**
> FastAPI app, or you need to perform **small** background tasks (like
> sending an email notification), you can simply just use
> `BackgroundTasks`.

Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71517830/17865804) as well.