# How to trigger a Python function asynchronously from a handler function of FastAPI and move on without waiting for its response?

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, async-await, fastapi

I have a FastAPI handler function say fast_api_func and another function say func_to_be_called which I want to trigger from the fast_api_func asynchronously. I do not want to wait for its results. Once it is triggered, I want to return some response from the API so that the func_to_be_called keeps running in the background until finished.

Something like this:

```
async def func_to_be_called():
   #do some stuff which takes time

@app.post("/fast-api-endpoint")
def fast_api_func(request: dict = Body(...)):
   func_to_be_called()
   return "Ok"
```

Here, response "Ok" should be returned without waiting for completion of the execution of func_to_be_called function.

I have tried calling it directly, also with asyncio functions and loops but couldn't make it work. Either it gives await required error or executes the function synchronously & then returns "Ok" or returns "Ok" first but background execution doesn't happen. Response "Ok" should be returned without waiting for the completion of the execution of func_to_be_called function.

Can you suggest how to solve this?

Comment: Related answers can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76280152/17865804), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73283272/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73464007/17865804). You might find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70873984/17865804), as well as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71517830/17865804) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74508996/17865804) helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [background tasks](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/background-tasks/#using-backgroundtasks)

```py
from fastapi import BackgroundTasks, FastAPI

app = FastAPI()

async def func_to_be_called():
    #do some stuff which takes time

@app.post("/fast-api-endpoint")
async def fast_api_func(bt: BackgroundTasks):
    bt.add_task(func_to_be_called)
    return "OK"
```